# Calculate Trim Mean for different Tasks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel sheet with different tasks done by different people and their daily counts also. I want to calculate **trim mean** for each of the task. The sheet is daily updated. So the numbers are getting changed daily.

```
Person   Task   Count  Date

P1       TK1    100    1/1/18
P2       TK1    500    1/1/18
P3       TK2    200    1/1/18
P1       TK3    500    1/2/18
P3       TK1    200    1/2/18
P4       TK2    500    1/2/18
P1       TK1    750    1/3/18
```

The sheet looks like above. Now I want to get trim Mean of task **TK1**. The trimmean() function only takes array as input. So is there any way I can the data in the following format

```
TK1   100   500   200  750
TK2   200   500
TK3   500
```

or the trim mean get calculated for each of the tasks?

I guess the only way is VBA, but I have no clue, how to get different task data in to an array to process.

Comment: Can't you use pivot-tables for that?

Comment: Pivot table wont refresh itself. And Im not sure I can calculate trim mean from Pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below array formula (You should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just an <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=TRIMMEAN(IF(B2:B8="TK1",C2:C8,""),0)
```

Since I do not know your requirement of percentage for `TRIMMEAN` I have used 0. You may change that second parameter according to your need. You should use 0.10 for %10 trim.

Comment: I got the mean as result, not Trimmean

Comment: That's because I have used **0** as `TRIMMEAN` 's parameter. You should change that part to the desired percentage such as 0.10, 0.20 etc.

Comment: I used like '=TRIMMEAN(IF(Daily_Count!B:B=B4,Daily_Count!D:D,""),0.8)'
still I got mean only

Comment: OOPS, My bad, Took wrong column... It worked perfectly... Thanks Hakan